How do I make everything on a page that responds to a click also respond to enter and spacebar keys with jQuery?
As an accessibility consultant, one thing I run into a LOT is controls that work on mouse click, but not on enter or spacebar. There are plenty of examples of how to add key functionality to specific elements, but nothing generic. It occurred to me that I could kill a lot of birds with one stone and save a lot of time if I had a script that would:

look for everything that responds to a click event and
add spacebar and enter key functionality to it

Is that possible?
Edit: I guess I should have posted an example, because people seem to kind of missing the point. In the example here, the headings respond to mouse click, but don't respond to enter key, even though they receive keyboard focus.
$(".haccordian h1, .haccordian h2, .haccordian h3, .haccordian h4, .haccordian h5, .haccordian h6").addClass("h-trigger").next().addClass("h-section collapsed");

$(".h-trigger").attr("tabindex","0");

$(".h-trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".h-section").toggleClass("collapsed");
  });
});

<div class="haccordian">
<h2>Section with a paragraph</h2>
<p>Here is some text content</p>
</div>

There are a lot of things I encounter like that (spans made to look like buttons, etc). The roles of those things are irrelevant to this question. I just want to find all "clickable" non-native elements and make them work with the keyboard. If there is no possible way to do that, then that is the answer.

This current approach is not a good way to build an accessible accordion. As Andy notes in their answer, you really need to use built-in, semantic interactive elements for clickable elements. In this case, a button. See this example from the W3C's WAI where they use buttons inside of headings.

A clickable heading is wrong per se, I'm sorry. It's again violating the whole semantics. A heading is where I navigate to, not what I expect to click.

This is probably possible, but it's not accessible. To continue your analogy, you'll kill three birds instead of two, and the third one is your chasing falcon.
"Everything that is clickable" cannot be shot at one time because you need to thoroughly think what is each of those clickable things: a link, a button, a drop-down menu button etc. Every type of semantically correct DOM element has its own role and its own behavior. Also, Space and enter are not enough. Consider a link, for example:

It must be focusable on Tab key;
It must be exposed as link to the accessibility technologies because, for example, screen readers have ways of listing all the links on the webpage and telling the user the number of links immediately as they navigate to the page. Also, links are underlined on a Braille display, while "something clickable" like a <span> is not;
A link must be visibly prominent for low-vision users (this is not my piece of cake really, but read the WCAG criteria for more info).

We screen reader users use many techniques that simplify our life. For example, there are quick navigation keys that allow us to jump from a button to the next button, from a visited link to the next one, and so on, and so forth.
Long story short, what you propose violates many accessibility criteria outlined in WCAG (Web Content Accessibility Guidelines).

I guess you missed the part where I said I was an accessibility specialist (CPWA). This does NOT violate California law. It fixes the WCAG violation of keyboard alone. The matter of name, role, value, is a separate issue which would need to be handled separately and individually for each component. And yes, I realize that the things need to be focusable, I've already handled that. In my test case, I'm using Test

Well, a heading is not an element that expects to be focusable per se. Also, again as a screen reader user myself, why should I even expect to press Enter on a heading if it is not a link or a button? And buttons and links inside of headings seem to me utterly wrong as a phenomenon, also.

If actions are bound to the click event on native interactive elements, Space and Enter already work!

An element receives a click event when any of the following occurs:
[…]

the Space key or Enter key is pressed while the element is focused


Try it:


<button onclick="console.log('Clicked')">Focus me and press enter</button>



If this doesn’t work on a page, no native controls were used, and probably the following are missing as well:

The controls have no or an incorrect ARIA role, so users of assistive technology don’t know how to interact with them
They are not focusable, so one couldn’t press enter or space while they are focused

So while it might be possible to generically make sure that tabindex="0" and key handlers are added to these elements, it only solves part of the issue.
In the example from the question a heading is made the interactive element, which is incorrect. A button must be used inside the heading, and also expose its aria-expanded state. So adding key handlers alone will not fix that.
See the APG on Accordions for guidance.
There is no universal way in JavaScript to identify elements that have click handlers bound to them.
Given that the elements are not native ones, they will need some CSS class to achieve styling. You could, use these classes to identify the elements, and fix missing roles while at it.


// add tabindex and key handlers
document.querySelectorAll('.button, .link').forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
  el.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if ([" ", "Enter"].includes(e.key)) {
      e.target.click();
    }
  });
});

// fix roles
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(b => b.setAttribute("role", "button"));

document.querySelectorAll('.link').forEach(l => l.setAttribute("role", "button"));
.link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: .5em 0;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em 0;
  padding: .5em .2em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: .5em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="link" onclick="console.log('Link clicked')">A terrible, inaccessible link. Don’t do this</div>

<div class="button" onclick="console.log('Button clicked')">A terrible, inaccessible button. Don’t do this</div>




Thanks Andy. The first part of your statement is incorrect however. I guess I should have posted a code sample. In this example, all of the headings respond to mouse click, but do not respond to enter key, even though they are focusable:
$(".h-trigger").click(function(){
$(this).next(".h-section").toggleClass("collapsed");
});
});

Section with a paragraph
Here is some text content

See edit to my question above.

I don’t see how this renders my statement incorrect. Headings are not native interactive elements.

While we could certainly well imagine a script to list all focusable elements, or all clickable elements, it would be incorrect to generalize and make them all react the same way upon pressing enter or space key.
First of all, buttons, links, and several form elements already correctly handle enter and/or space key natively.
By trying to handle enter or space key yourself on these elements, you are doing unnecessary work, and you have great chances to don't provide any benefit while creating bugs: double trigger, or making the element not exactly behaving like a normal one for example. So it's much safer to don't do anything above standard handling on these elements.
Secondly, many screen readers simulate a click when pressing enter and/or space when the reading cursor is on a clickable element. But they don't necessarily do it in all cases, it can depend on whether the document or focus cursor is active for example.
All screen readers don't do it exactly on the same way, on the same elements, in the same cases. They themselves try to guess more or less well when they need to do it or not precisely to go against the lack of accessibility.
YYou don't know well if the key event is transmitted to the element or not in such a case, which leads back to the first point.
By adding your own key handlers above all that mess, you are very likely to create more mess !
While it's correct that you need to handle enter and/or space on custom elements, it's impossible to generalize. Pressing enter and/or space doesn't always the same action as a click. Pressing enter on an input field will trigger submission of a form for example, while clicking only place the focus on it.
In fact, the root conceptual design error is to use plain <span> or <div> where you should have used the appropriate elements for the right things.
In fact, stop overthinking. You have some text or an icon producing an action when clicked ? That's a <button>. It opens another page instead ? That's a link. It's something you can turn on/off ? That's <input type="checkbox"/>. It opens/closes/shows/hides some content ? <detail>. And so on.
You make triple benefit by using standard elements: it's accessible out of the box, you don't need to handle clinky scripts to fill the gaps, and you can concentrate on your real business.
In reality, accessibility is very simple, very well thought, and visual appearence isn't a valid excuse, since you can do almost what you want with CSS.
If you are accessibility consultant, you should probably have to transmit this kind of mindset to lead your clients toward better accessibility.

Sorry, but I'm a blind user myself. Probably that I can technically answer the question and make your script, but it isn't good for accessibility, and as you can see, I'm not alone to say that. To take an example from your other comments, you shouldn't think <h2 tabindex="0"> but rather <h2><a> if your heading does something when clicked. It's screen reader and keyboard accessible out of the box without the need to make any script. Your first goal shouldn't be to fix crazy things with dubious scripts, but prevent them in the first place.

No, you shouldn't do that. Why would you create a link to something directly below it? And I'm not "fixing crazy things with a dubious script" haha! Adding a bunch of buttons, links, and roles to a section which is just a series of headings and content is stupid, and makes it less accessible.

Without context, without code, I can't say if something is stupid or not. I try to answer with the info I have. However, as an accessibility expert, you should know the first ARIA rule: don't use it, unless you really need to. It's the same with tabindex. So in that regard, <h2><a> is certainly better and more accessible than <h2 tabindex="0">. As already said in another answer, keyboard focus isn't the only concern. And if your thing is supposed to be used by one kind of people but not the other, you have a bigger accessibility problem.
